# Can't create a IBOutlet for WebKit view in Swift 4

Tags: swift, webkit

I am trying to put a website in the middle of my storyboard.  When I add the view controller and try to connect it to a new ViewController, I cannot control-drag the object to create the Outlet.  I can create outlets for Labels and buttons, and all the rest of the normal objects.  Just not for the webkit view control. It works if I try it in a new project just like it is supposed to. Is this a bug or is something in my program blocking web content? 
There is no code to share since I can't get that far.

Comment: try deleting derived data (clean) and build

Answer (score 1):

I understood your problem. Such kind of thing sometimes happen with me.
I uses a one tick to solve this problem. I copy the outlet of other control and then i rename it and change the property to my requirement. 
  For Example,
     @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

After then you can connect outlets to your control.

It works fine.